# Strange changing of vAriable in middle of C code

Tags: c, arrays

I have written a certain program to calculate a nonlinear integral equation. The C-code is written below. The problem is that I initialize the array "Delta" in the step I denoted by `*"/*` Initialize the array for theta and Delta and check whether the array delta sums to one*/"*. The gives me an array for delta with values between zero and 1, which monotonically increase. After that I do not use the array anymore.

However, after I have run the loop which I denote by `*"/*` Now we initialize the matrix Kernel `*/"*,`the value of the elements in Delta changes to ridiculous values. This is weird as I do not assign any new values to Delta in this loop. In fact, by printing the value of Delta in that loop I have discovered that everything goes well, until the last run of the loop: it is in this run that the values of Delta are changed.

I have been staring at this for a day now, but I cannot find the problem. Maybe someone else can spot my mistake?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define PI 3.14159265
main()
{
  int i,j,k;

  int gridsize, gridsizetwo = 200;

  printf("What gridsize would you like to use?\n");
  scanf("%d",&gridsize);

  float Theta[gridsize-1], Delta[gridsize-1], sum=0;
  double Kernel[gridsize-1][gridsize-1];

  /* Initialize the array for theta and Delta and check whether the array delta sums to one*/

  for (i=0 ; i<gridsize ; i++)
    {
      Theta[i] = PI/2*(i+1)/(gridsize + 1);

      if (i==0)
      { Delta[i] = 1 - 0.5*(cos(PI/2*(i+1)/(gridsize + 1)) + cos(PI/2*(i+2)/(gridsize + 1)));
        sum = sum + Delta[i]; }
      else if (i==gridsize-1)
      { Delta[i] = 0.5*(cos(PI/2*gridsize/(gridsize + 1)) + cos(PI/2*(gridsize-1)/(gridsize + 1)));
        sum = sum + Delta[i]; }
      else
      { Delta[i] = 0.5*(cos(PI/2*(i)/(gridsize + 1)) - cos(PI/2*(i+2)/(gridsize + 1)));
        sum = sum + Delta[i]; }
      printf("Theta %f   Delta %f    Sum of Delta %f\n", Theta[i], Delta[i], sum); 
    } 

  /* Initialize array for Phi seperately */
  float Phi[gridsizetwo-1];
  for (i=0 ; i<gridsizetwo ; i++)
  {
    Phi[i] = 2*PI*(i+1)/(gridsizetwo + 1);
    /* printf("Phi: %f\n",Phi[i]); */
  }

  /* Now we initialize the matrix Kernel */
  float help, helpp, helppp;

  for (i=0 ; i<gridsize ; i++)
    {
    for(j=0 ; j<gridsize-1 ; j++)
      {
        /* Use help variables to calculate lengthy parts of matrix kernel seperately */
        help = sqrt(1 - pow(cos(Theta[i])*cos(Theta[j]) + sin(Theta[i])*sin(Theta[j])*cos(Phi[0]),2));
        helppp = sqrt(1 - pow(cos(Theta[i])*cos(Theta[j]) + sin(Theta[i])*sin(Theta[j])*cos(Phi[gridsizetwo-1]),2));

        for (k=1 ; k<=gridsizetwo-2 ; k++)
        { if (k==1) { helpp=0; }
          helpp = helpp + sqrt(1-pow(cos(Theta[i])*cos(Theta[j])+sin(Theta[i])*sin(Theta[j])*cos(Phi[k]),2)); }
        /* Correct combination of help variables now yields matrix kernel */
        Kernel[i][j] = 2*PI/(gridsizetwo+1)*(3/2*help + helpp + 3/2*helppp);
      }
      for (k=0 ; k<gridsize ; k++)
      {
        printf("Delta = %f\n",Delta[k]);
      }
    }  
/* End the program */
}
```

Comment: your arrays should be gridsize and not gridsize - 1 for the loop you are using.  your arrays are one element smaller than they should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  double Kernel[gridsize-1][gridsize-1];
  // ...
  for (i=0 ; i<gridsize ; i++)
    {
    for(j=0 ; j<gridsize-1 ; j++)
      {
        // ...
        Kernel[i][j] = 2*PI/(gridsizetwo+1)*(3/2*help + helpp + 3/2*helppp);
      }
      // ...
    }
```

Notice something odd about `i` and `j`?
You are accessing `Kernel` elements that do not exist.

Comment: I am always confused by the fact that C counts the first element of an array by zero... I guess this comes from that. Thanks!

Comment: It takes some getting used to, especially if you have experience otherwise. But after a while you'll hate 1-based indexing :)

Comment: It gets easier to understand once you figure out that index is an *offset*, rather than intended to represent the nth element. In other words, how many elements away from the beginning do you have to go to get to the first element? Zero, since the first one is right at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

If you declare `float Theta[gridsize-1];`, then the number of elements is `gridsize-1`, and the allowed indexes are 0, 1, ..., `gridsize-2`.

Make sure that your arrays are large enough for your needs, and you don't use too small or too large indexes. In this case it can be as simple as changing `gridsize-1` to `gridsize` in the declarations. If that doesn't fix the problem, update the question with the new sizes.